# Controller method: passing values via POST vs. signature

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
//method declaration
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Step2_UpdateCart(bool? isNextStepClicked)

//one of many of the view's fields processed by the method
<input type="hidden" name="isNextStepClicked" value="false" />
```

I'm reverse engineering a View/Controller set where a form within the view has a series of inputs that are passed via the Submit. One of the inputs is a hidden field - it's name is found in the method's signature - and is the only value found in the signature - the rest of the values come from the Request object.

I thought perhaps it might be a case where the method could recursively call itself with a different value than the form carried but i don't see that happening anywhere.

Does this make any sense? (either my question or my code sample).

many thanx

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Why do you even need isNextStepClicked when you hide it and set it's value to false? Apparently it's always false then. So if it's always the same (false) you don't need it. Just assume in the controller action it is false. However, the way you have it, it should always be initialized - to false. MAybe try removing the question mark next to the bool type...Besides, you might want to explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: I didn't include the view code where isNextStepClicked will be tripped to true (or not, depending on validation routines). My problem is understanding exactly what the code I'm inheriting is doing within the very narrow context of why only one of many of the View's fields is showing up in the signature and the rest are being passed via the request object.

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find its better to take advantage of input models or the `FormCollection` type.  With the first option, you get to define your properties, and MVC's default model binder will do its best to map them across.  E.g.:

```
public ActionResult Step2_UpdateCart(UpdateCartInputModel model)
```

Where `UpdateCartInputModel` could be defined as:

```
public class UpdateCartInputModel {
    public bool? isNextStepClicked { get; set; }
    public bool? isSomeOtherPropertyClicked { get; set; }
}
```

With the `FormCollection`, MVC treats this as a special case and where an action accepts an instance of `FormCollection` it will fill it:

```
public ActionResult Step2_UpdateCart(FormCollection form)
```

With a `FormCollection`, you have to handle the type casting/conversion yourself.

I personally don't see any need to try and build some complex recursive controller action, when what you need could be accomplished doing either of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking "where is the parameter coming from?" and by parameter I mean the bool? isNextStepClicked signature parameter. There are three ways that a Controller ActionResult can be called to my knowledge.

The first is a straight call from another Action using RedirectToAction.  The next is as listed above - from the form, where a control is declared with the same ID  as your named parameter (e.g.  gives a signature of public ActionResult ViewName (string information).   Personally I find this irritating as I like to have all my code with the correct type of casing - but because most form ID's begin with an upper case, so do my signature parameters.

Thirdly, there is the straight constructor call. This is the worst as there is no way to trace it being called from the markup using Shift+F12 (find all usages).  Some parameters can be named but not called. A controller doesn't need values for each parameter.

Hope this helps you. :-)